# what is wrong with my jquery tabber code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Somebody please save me! I'm so frustrated don't know what I'm doing wrong. What is wrong with my code? It activates a particular tab based on the URL. For example, `www.mywebsite.com#tab3` will activate tab3 of my tabber. This is how I'm achieving this: I use `location.hash` to get the location and compare with href, then activate that tab. But here lies the problem: I've two differently styled tabs (`ul#tabs li a` and `ul.tabs li a`). Am I selecting and doing the comaparison well? This is the code:

```
 var hash = location.hash;


 $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content

 if ($("ul#tabs li a[href='" + hash + "'], ul.tabs li a[href='" + hash + "']").length) {
     $("ul#tabs li a[href='" + hash + "'], ul.tabs li a[href='" + hash + "']").parent().addClass("active"); //Activate tab
     $(hash).show();
 }
```

Comment: What does it do? What doesn't it do? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: What @David said, plus I want a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) :)

Comment: @David, @Chad it activates a particular tab based on the URL so I use `location.hash` to get the location and compare with href then activate that tab. But I've 2 differently styled tabs (`ul#tabs li a` and `ul.tabs li a`).

Comment: Why not do another if statement that uses `$(ul.tabs li a[...])`?

Comment: @David that is what I want to avoid cuz I think it's an unnecssary repition.

Comment: @JoePaul My answer has a solution for that. See below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to facilitate this action:

```
var hash = location.hash;

function active_hash(type) {
    var $node = $("ul" + type + "tabs li a[href='" + hash + "'], ul.tabs li a[href='" + hash + "']");

    if ($node.length) {
        $node.parent().addClass("active");
        $(hash).show();
    }
}

active_hash('#');
active_hash('.');
```